# HTML5 audio with HLS streaming with DVR timeshift on Samsung Internet

Tags: html, audio, samsung-browser

i am trying to make a web based streaming player (http://srv.deutschlandradio.de/themes/streamplayer/index.html) work for Samsung Internet (Samsung's Android stock browser), without success.

The stream plays, but I am unable to control it's position. It seems that Samsung's browser supports basic HLS streaming, but no seeking (nor live playing) of streams with DVR (DVR functionality allows viewers to pause, play, and rewind live streams for a certain time).

For example, `audioElement.currentTime` always returns 0, and changing it's value, it switches back to 0 every time.

This works fine on other browsers (as documented here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp).

Is there any documentation on streaming support with DVR window for Samsung Internet?

I am asking Samsung directly at the same time, but as [Peter O'Shaughnessy suggests](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/introducing-samsung-internet-for-developers-6c3a3be42f72#.82u5qrhvm) I am posting it here. I still hope I am not the only one who tried to implement this on StackOverflow... Maybe there are some workarounds? MediaSourceExtensions are not supported either, as it seems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The samsung browser, known as "Samsung Internet", does not seem to support MediaSource Extensions, see this thread for more details: https://github.com/SamsungInternet/support/issues/5

It behaves exactly as chrome without MediaSource extensions.